# Jenkins description setter is not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins. I started using this plugin called "Description-setter"

https://plugins.jenkins.io/description-setter

**Basically, I want to set build ID in description after the build completes.**

I installed the plugin -> Post-build actions -> I added the plugin as below:

[image]

The regex works when I parse the build console.logs as below:

```js
const str = `angularjs@1_4_7-ie8 found in path(s):
public/components/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js

[INFO] Registered manifest into CMPaaS:
https://deploy-apixyz.com/swdeploy/v2/manifests/demonodeserver/versions/1.0.0_20180628165604811

Your build metrics have been recorded with id
demonodeserver-06-29T00:07:42.845Z and manifest_id
demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811`;

const regex = /demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+/gm;

const match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

**Problem:**
Just when I thought everything is working, After the build Finishes I see the following error:

> Successfully completed the CI Build
>
> [description-setter] Could not determine description.
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

I am not sure why it's not able to determine description. I think I'm missing something, can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Regexp field did not expect a real Regexp it will be already masked with "/" in the plugin. So I expect the correct input should be something like this:

```
demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+
```

Next thing the Description field only is filled with the first group, when left empty.

So I better to include the first group in the Description:

```
Build ID: \1
```

However the first group would be the first number with a dot. So the regexp should use another group around the id:

```
demonodeserver-((\d\.?){3})_\w+
```

Could not retest this since not at work, but will do this when I am back at my desk.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me test it out.

Comment: So in the regular expression field, should i use `demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+
` or `demonodeserver-((\d\.?){3})_\w+`

Comment: The second one but it will only catch the 1.0.0 if you also want the timestamp use the parentheses around everything: `demonodeserver-((\d\.?){3}_\w+)`

Comment: Ah, I see. I just want to see `demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811` without the timestamp. Thanks for the help. I will test it out with `demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+`

Comment: It works but I get `Build ID: 0` instead of `demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811` for `demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+`  :(

Comment: Try using this pattern and check which string he captured: `(demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+)`. Also add \2 (maybe also \3 \4) to the description string. Maybe he counts the groups differently. When this did not work. I will reply tommorow when I can test with a Jenkins instance.

Comment: I've kicked another build. Is there anyway to test this regEx without actually re-kicking builds everytime? :( Cuz each build takes ~30 min to finish completely. Just wondering if there's anyway to quickly run it on jsfiddle and test it out.

(PS: I tried running `str.match(RegEx)` but that didn't play well)

Comment: If you can create jobs in jenkins just build a freestyle job. But your output in a echo command in a shell block and apply the descriptor plugin (this is how i will test it). This should run in like some seconds max.

Comment: w00t.. you're the man. This works!!! :D Thanks my friend.

I used `(demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+)` with `Build ID: \1` works!

You deserve the bounty!